# Access child styles in parent component vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm passing in content via a slot to my child component from the parent component, I expect that it should pick up the style contained within `child.scss` but it doesn't apply the styling.

Using `::v-deep &__toggleAlternative {}` it works correctly, the child styles are applied. However this is deprecated and I can't seem to get it to work with `:deep` or `:slotted`

What is the correct approach to getting the child styling to work from the parent component?

**Parent.js**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <child>
      <p class="availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative --body --inheritColor">
        Show something
      </p>
    </child>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./parent.js" />
<style lang="scss" scoped src="./parent.scss" />
```

**child.scss**

```scss
.availabilityStatus {
  :deep(&__toggleAlternative) {
    color: inherit;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

I tried to use :slotted and :deep but it did not apply the child styles

Answer (score 1):

Because `.availabilityStatus` is not inside `:deep()` it will get appended by Vue with `[v-wh473v3r]` (where `wh473v3r` is a unique identifier for the current (parent) component, assigned by Vue at compile time).

The child selector you're trying to produce is `.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative`, not `.availabilityStatus[v-wh473v3r]__toggleAlternative` or `.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative[v-wh473v3r]` (because `v-wh473v3r` attribute is uniquely scoped to the parent, not to the child), meaning you should use either:

```scss
:deep(.availabilityStatus) {
  &__toggleAlternative {
    foo: bar;
  }
}
```

which correctly produces this CSS:

```css
.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative {
  foo: bar;
}
```

...or

```scss
:slotted(.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative) {
  foo: bar;
}
```

The above need to be inside parent, not in child.

Note that wrapping the parent selector into `:deep()` prevents Vue from adding the unique identifier to that selector, which means the CSS rules you place inside this selector will apply to any `.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative` in your page, not only to the current component's children.

If you need scoping, you'll need to move it into the child component:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative {
  foo: bar;
}
</style>
```

which will produce

```
.availabilityStatus__toggleAlternative[v-s0m3th1ng] {
  foo: bar;
}
```

, where `s0m3th1ng` is a unique identifier for the child component, not for the parent.

---

To fully understand how scoping works in Vue I recommend inspecting the DOM elements produced by your component(s) and paying attention to the `v-*****` attributes placed on each `scoped` component and how they relate to the `<style>` contents injected by Vue into `<head>`.

---

If you can't get what I explained above to work, consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (in codesandbox.io or similar) and explain clearly what you're trying to achieve (what styles should apply to what component and not apply to what other components).